# Update TextView value in Activity upon receiving FirebaseMessage

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity (MainActivity) and FireBaseMessagingService. I want to set value of a TextView in MainActivity upon receiving a Firebase message. For eg if i sent a firebase message "Good Morning", i want my value of TextView in MainActivity to be "Good Morning".

Here's what i tried:

1. I tried creating a reference of MainActivity in FireBaseMessagingService and then setting value of received message. (FAILED)
2. Tried creating a getter in MainActivity (Couldn't do it,confused)
3. Implementing FireBaseMessaging service in MainActivity (error)

I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide code to show us what exactly you have tried to do.

Comment: Use the **ResultReceiver** http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  A different flag may work better, I'm still learning about the different flags.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to add the info you need to the extras so you can get it in the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value exp:"Good Morning" and save in Shared Preferences ([Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)) key and when the MainActivity loading, read this key and showing.